# 4x4 TicTacToe with Minimax Algorithm

Tags: c++, tic-tac-toe, minimax

I have written **3x3 TicTacToe** using **Minimax.** It was working fine. Then I wanted to improve it to make it also playable as **4x4**. I changed and added some lines, it still works for 3x3, but it doesn't work for **CPU in 4x4 board.** What should I do?
If you need you can find the first and working version (3x3) [here](https://github.com/fuadshahmuradov/TicTacToe/blob/master/xo.cpp).

```
#include<iostream>
#include<limits>
using namespace std;

int index1,tablechoice,size=1;
char* board= new char[size];

int isFull()
{
    for(int i =0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(board[i]!='X' && board[i]!='O')
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    return 1;
}

int user_won()
{
    if(tablechoice==1)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<9; i+=3)
        {
            if((board[i]==board[i+1])&&(board[i+1]==board[i+2])&&(board[i]=='X'))
                return 1;
        } //checking horizontally
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            if((board[i]==board[i+3])&&(board[i+3]==board[i+6])&&(board[i]=='X'))
                return 1;
        } // checking vertically
        if((board[0]==board[4])&&(board[4]==board[8])&&(board[0]=='X'))
        {
            return 1;
        } //checking diagonal
        if((board[2]==board[4])&&(board[4]==board[6])&&(board[2]=='X'))
        {
            return 1;
        } //checking diagonal
        return 0;
    }
    if(tablechoice==2)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<16; i+=4)
        {
            if((board[i]==board[i+1])&&(board[i+1]==board[i+2])&&(board[i]=='X'))
                return 1;
        } //checking horizontally
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            if((board[i]==board[i+4])&&(board[i+4]==board[i+8])&&(board[i]=='X'))
                return 1;
        } // checking vertically
        if((board[0]==board[5])&&(board[5]==board[10])&&(board[10]==board[15])&&(board[0]=='X'))
        {
            return 1;
        } //checking diagonal
        if((board[3]==board[6])&&(board[6]==board[9])&&(board[9]==board[12])&&(board[3]=='X'))
        {
            return 1;
        } //checking diagonal
    }
}

int cpu_won()
{
    if(tablechoice==1)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<9; i+=3)
        {
            if((board[i]==board[i+1])&&(board[i+1]==board[i+2])&&(board[i]=='O'))
                return 1;
        } //checking horizontally
        for(int i=0; i<3; i++)
        {
            if((board[i]==board[i+3])&&(board[i+3]==board[i+6])&&(board[i]=='O'))
                return 1;
        } // checking vertically
        if((board[0]==board[4])&&(board[4]==board[8])&&(board[0]=='O'))
        {
            return 1;
        } //checking diagonal
        if((board[2]==board[4])&&(board[4]==board[6])&&(board[2]=='O'))
        {
            return 1;
        } //checking diagonal
        return 0;
    }
    if(tablechoice==2)
    {
        for(int i=0; i<16; i+=4)
        {
            if((board[i]==board[i+1])&&(board[i+1]==board[i+2])&&(board[i]=='O'))
                return 1;
        } //checking horizontally
        for(int i=0; i<4; i++)
        {
            if((board[i]==board[i+4])&&(board[i+4]==board[i+8])&&(board[i]=='O'))
                return 1;
        } // checking vertically
        if((board[0]==board[5])&&(board[5]==board[10])&&(board[10]==board[15])&&(board[0]=='O'))
        {
            return 1;
        } //checking diagonal
        if((board[3]==board[6])&&(board[6]==board[9])&&(board[9]==board[12])&&(board[3]=='O'))
        {
            return 1;
        } //checking diagonal
        return 0;
    }
}

void displayBoard()
{
    if(tablechoice==1)
    {
        cout<<"\n-----------------------------TIC TAC TOE------------------------------";
        cout<<"                 ### Created by Fuad Shahmuradov ###";
        cout<<"\n\n\n\n[1][2][3]\n"
            <<"[4][5][6]\n"
            <<"[7][8][9]\n";
        cout<<"\t\t-------------\n"
            <<"\t\t| "<<board[0]<<" | "<<board[1]<<" | "<<board[2]<<" |\n"
            <<"\t\t-------------\n"
            <<"\t\t| "<<board[3]<<" | "<<board[4]<<" | "<<board[5]<<" |\n"
            <<"\t\t-------------\n"
            <<"\t\t| "<<board[6]<<" | "<<board[7]<<" | "<<board[8]<<" |\n"
            <<"\t\t-------------\n";
    }
    if(tablechoice==2)
    {
        cout<<"\n-----------------------------TIC TAC TOE------------------------------";
        cout<<"                 ### Created by Fuad Shahmuradov ###";
        cout<<"\n[1 ][2 ][3 ][4 ]\n"
              <<"[5 ][6 ][7 ][8 ]\n"
              <<"[9 ][10][11][12]\n"
              <<"[13][14][15][16]\n";
        cout<<"\t\t-----------------\n"
            <<"\t\t| "<<board[0]<<" | "<<board[1]<<" | "<<board[2]<<" | "<<board[3]<<" | \n"
            <<"\t\t-----------------\n"
            <<"\t\t| "<<board[4]<<" | "<<board[5]<<" | "<<board[6]<<" | "<<board[7]<<" | \n"
            <<"\t\t-----------------\n"
            <<"\t\t| "<<board[8]<<" | "<<board[9]<<" | "<<board[10]<<" | "<<board[11]<<" | \n"
            <<"\t\t-----------------\n"
            <<"\t\t| "<<board[12]<<" | "<<board[13]<<" | "<<board[14]<<" | "<<board[15]<<" | \n"
            <<"\t\t-----------------\n";
    }
    else return;
}

int minimax(bool flag)
{
    int max_val=-1000, min_val=1000;
    int i,j,value=1;
    if (cpu_won() == 1)
    {
        return 10;
    }
    else if (user_won() == 1)
    {
        return -10;
    }
    else if (isFull() == 1)
    {
        return 0;
    }
    int score[size];
    for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
    {
        score[i]=1; //if score[i]=1 then it is empty
    }
    for(i=0; i<size; i++)
    {
        if(board[i] == ' ')
        {
            if(min_val>max_val)
            {
                if(flag == true)
                {
                    board[i] = 'O';
                    value = minimax(false);
                }
                else
                {
                    board[i] = 'X';
                    value = minimax(true);
                }
                board[i] = ' ';
                score[i] = value;
            }
        }
    }
    if(flag == true)
    {
        max_val = -1000;
        for(j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            if(score[j] > max_val && score[j] != 1)
            {
                max_val = score[j];
                index1 = j;
            }
        }
        return max_val;
    }
    if(flag == false)
    {
        min_val = 1000;
        for(j=0; j<size; j++)
        {
            if(score[j] < min_val && score[j] != 1)
            {
                min_val = score[j];
                index1 = j;
            }
        }
        return min_val;
    }
}

void playGame()
{
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++)
        {
            board[i]=' ';
        }
        int player,choice;
        cout<<endl<<"\nUSER--->(X)      CPU------>(O)";
        cout<<endl<<"\nSELECT:\n1-> Player first \n2-> CPU first\t\t";
        cin>>choice;
        cout<<"\n\n";
        if(choice==1)
        {
            displayBoard();
            up:cout<<endl<<"Enter your move: ";
            cin>>player;
            if(board[player-1]==' '&& cin)
            {
                board[player-1] = 'X';
                displayBoard();
            }
            else
            {
                cin.clear();
                cin.ignore(numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n');
                cout<<endl<<"Invalid move. Try different one.";
                goto up;
            }
        }
        while(true)
        {
            minimax(true);
            board[index1] = 'O';
            displayBoard();
            if(cpu_won()==1)
            {
                cout<<endl<<"CPU won!\n\n";
                break;
            }
            if(isFull()==1)
            {
                cout<<endl<<"Tie!\n\n";
                break;
            }
            again:cout<<endl<<"Enter your move: ";
            cin>>player;
            if(board[player-1]==' ')
            {
                board[player-1] = 'X';
                displayBoard();
            }
            else
            {
                cout<<endl<<"Invalid move. Try different one!\n";
                goto again;
            }
            if(user_won()==1)
            {
                cout<<endl<<"You won!\n\n";
                break;
            }
            if(isFull() == 1)
            {
                cout<<endl<<"Tie!\n\n";
                break;
            }
        }
}
int main()
{
    cout<<"-----------------------------TIC TAC TOE------------------------------";
    cout<<"                 ### Created by Fuad Shahmuradov ###";
    select:cout<<endl<<"\nSelect game mode:\n1-> 3X3 \n2-> 4X4\t\t\t";
    cin>>tablechoice;
    if(tablechoice==1)
    {
        size=9;
        playGame();
        return 0;
    }
    if(tablechoice==2)
    {
        size=16;
        playGame();
        return 0;
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"\nInvalid choice!";
        goto select;
    }

}
```

Comment: Rather than saying "it doesn't work", describe what it does do and what you want it to do instead. Not only does it make the question easier for us to answer, often writing down the differences between the received and the expected shakes the answer loose.

Comment: Unrelated (probably): the `goto` in `main` can be replaced by a `while` loop.

Comment: @user4581301 , basically I want it to play against me. If I start first, and place an 'X' in a tile, CPU should place an 'O' in another place using the algorithm. But it stops when it is CPU's turn, and nothing happens. If I close the console, it says `Process terminated with status -1073741510 (0 minute(s), 16 second(s))`.

Comment: I would say your problem is not the min max but - no offense - coding style. It makes it much better to read if you pass variables through the functions instead of global definitions and the goto is a "no go" like said before - always use "while" or "do while". Also using "enums" instead of char + array will cut the code in big way.
I never used minmax before but I like the library and always wanted to create a clever tic tac toe game. My first step would be to just get min max working with 2 simple options instead of 9 like here https://cutt.ly/Me23NbR

Comment: Have you used the debugging utility that came with your development environment to investigate what lead up to the unexpected termination?